# Increase elements of array in a certain interval by a certain amount. JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array A of size N. I have there integers S, E and I. I need to increment all array elements from index S to E by I.

Values of S and E are guaranteed to be logically correct

My attempt:

```
for(int i=S; i<=E; i++)
{
A[i]=A[i]+I;
}
```

Is there a faster way to do the same?

Comment: I assume that you are checking that `E`  is less than `A.length - 1`

Comment: No there isn't, why do you think this way is *slow* ?

Comment: "Is there a faster way to do the same?" No, that's about as fast as it gets. (As John3136 says, using `A[i] += I` **may** make a fractional difference, but you'd need to benchmark it to find out.)

Comment: @alfasin maybe there is an in-built function in JAVA for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your approach is correct. You could do `A[i] += I` but there is no change you can make to speed it up by "orders of magnitude"

Comment: is `A[i] += I` really any faster than `A[i]=A[i]+I` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I think not, and my guess is that the underlying byte code would be identical, at least in many cases.

Comment: @ScaryWombat probably not. But I'm old enough to remember 68K assembly where `++` in C compiled to a specific `INC` op code that was a couple of cycles faster than the non `INC` version, so call it habit ;-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: The byte code isn't identical (I checked) - but whether the JIT-compiled code is or not is a different matter.

Comment: does java compilers optimize to use simd instructions?

Answer (score 1):

you are not ensuring no error if S or E are greater than N.

i would do:

```
for (int i=S; i<=E && i<N; i++) {
    A[i] += I;
}
```

Also, be sure you are interested in element between S and E, with E being included (talking about the = on the condition to end the loop).

Aside from that, i see no better option in terms of being faster.

Comment: As per the OP's comment - shall we assume that these checks are being done

Comment: If you go that way, why don't you also check that S is bigger than zero, or that A is not null. That's usually not a correct thing to do. If a method has well-defined preconditions, the caller must respect them. If the caller gets an exception by not respecting these preconditions, the caller code should be fixed, instead of silently accepting arguments that are invalid.

Comment: by the  time i started answering those comments were not there :) .

Comment: @JBNizet i did not add that check as a way to avoid developer bug, is not a paranoid nullcheck. I added since it was not clear if N could be legally lower than E. It could be runtime data not controlled by user and OP didn't tell if that case was already handled or not. A for sure could not be null from the OP description. S is ok to be 0 from OP description also.